# Loading a DLL as Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net, sqlclr

I'm trying to load a DLL (written in VB) without success.

The DLL source code follows (logic omitted for simplicity):

```vb
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Namespace UWQ_Excel_Compute

    Public Class UWQ_IF_to_Excel

        Public Sub P_Excel_Calculate(ByVal p_File_Reference  ,
                                     ByVal p_Sheet_Reference ,
                                     ByVal p_In_Cells_Values ,
                                     ByVal p_Result_Cell     ,
                                     ByRef p_Result          ,
                                     ByRef p_Result_Code)

            <Start Procedure Logic>
            :
            :
            <End Procedure Logic>

            Excel_Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Excel_Workbook.Close()
            Excel_Application.Quit()
            Excel_Workbook = Nothing

            p_Result_Code = l_Return_Code
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

The Assembly creation command is:

```sql
CREATE ASSEMBLY UWQ_Excel_Compute  
FROM 'C:\Lyb\UWQ_Excel_Compute.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

and the Procedure creation is:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [UWQ].[p_SYS_Excel_Compute] (@_p_File_Reference     NVARCHAR(512)   ,
                                              @_p_Sheet_Reference    NVARCHAR(64)    ,
                                              @_p_In_Cells_Values    NVARCHAR(512)   ,
                                              @_p_Result_Cell        NVARCHAR(16)    ,
                                              @_p_Result             FLOAT  OUTPUT   ,
                                              @_p_Result_Code        INT    OUTPUT     )

AS EXTERNAL NAME UWQ_Excel_Compute.[UWQ_IF_to_Excel].P_Excel_Calculate
```

After executing the last command (`CREATE PROCEDURE`), the following error message is received:

> Msg 6505, Level 16, State 2, Procedure p_SYS_Excel_Compute, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
>
> Could not find Type 'UWQ_IF_to_Excel' in assembly 'UWQ_Excel_Compute'.

I don't quite understand what I'm missing.

Comment: For starters, you'll need to annotate the method with [SqlProcedureAttribute] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlprocedureattribute). That's just the tip of the iceberg, though. COM interop from SQLCLR is the road less traveled for many reasons. This looks like an x-y problem.

Comment: It's [explicitly unsupported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) to even run Excel "normally" in an unattended fashion on a server. Doing so from inside of SQL Server is bound to be a spectacular disaster. Please don't do that.

Comment: Thank you @GSerg for your response. You may assume that I'm trying to implement this NOT because I like it but because I have no other option. The Excel file contains a tool to calculate very complex scientific coefficients, and it was certified by an international entity. Using a different mechanism would cause the user to lose his International accreditation and recognition. In any case, this calculation will only be invoked a few time (say, 10-20) a day, and will probably be running on a separate DB server for security reasons.

Comment: Arguably, you lose certification either way. Microsoft says that Excel is not guaranteed to work correctly in certain circumstances; the certification is hardly in a position to override this and declare that the file will calculate correctly despite Excel is malfunctioning.